# UWP Cambiar posición de una Ellipse que pertenece a una colección

Tags: xaml, uwp, mvvm

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
public class Chip
{
    public double PositionTop { get; set; }
    public double PositionLeft { get; set; }
    public double Size { get; set; }
    public SolidColorBrush Fill { get; set; }
}
```

Desde el ViewModel establezco una ObservableCollection Chips y en la vista tengo la siguiente representación.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Chips}"
                      Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="20"
                      Grid.Column="0 " Grid.ColumnSpan="20">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Canvas>
                        <Ellipse Canvas.Left="{Binding PositionLeft}" 
                                 Canvas.Top="{Binding PositionTop}" 
                                 Fill="{Binding Fill}"
                                 Style="{StaticResource Chip}"
                                 Width="{Binding Size}"
                                 Height="{Binding Size}"
                                 Tapped="ViewModel.UIElement_OnTapped"/>
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Al lanzar el evento Tapped mi intención es cambiar la posición desde el ViewModel, pero no logro saber qué elemento de la lista es el que ha sido pulsado, ya que no puedo hacer un "Cast" directo al tipo de objeto "Chip".
¿Alguna ayuda o alguna pista para investigar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucionado.

He cambiado el evento Tapped al elemento Canvas y he podido hacer el Cast al objeto Chip desde el Canvas.DataContext.

El inconveniente es que no se actualiza la posición directamente, por lo que elimino de la colección el objeto y añado un nuevo objeto con la posición deseada. De paso aprovecho para lanzar una animación desde la posición inicial a la posición final.

El código de evento queda así:

```
public void Chip_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var canvas = (Canvas)sender;
            var chip = (Chip)canvas.DataContext;
            var newChip = new Chip();
            newChip = chip;
            newChip.PositionTop = 175;
            newChip.PositionLeft = 175;
            Chips.Remove(chip);
            Chips.Add(newChip);
        }
```